# Java Hibernate : Update most recent entry in MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

This is my requirement. I have a bunch of rows with similar data. I want to update some columns on the LATEST entry. So I have written a hibernate query which goes like this

```
String hql = "UPDATE Studenttable T set T.timestamp=:time,T.Action=:action where T.StudentId=:studentId and T.teacherId=:TeacherId order by T.teacher_student_mapping_id DESC";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("time",time);
query.setParameter("studentId", studentId);
query.setParameter("TeacherId", teacherId);
query.setParameter("action", action);
query.setMaxResults(1);
query.executeUpdate();
```

What this does is it updates all the rows which satisfies the condition and then returns the latest row. Instead I want it to fetch the latest row satisfying the conditions, and then update it. How can I do it? Any help is deeply appreciated.

P.S. the teacher_student_mapping_id is an auto-generated value, which is also a primary key.

Time is the current time.

Please don't try to make sense of the table, I have changed the names of the columns for confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

try

String hql = "UPDATE Studenttable T set T.timestamp=:time,T.Action=:action where T.StudentId=:studentId and T.teacherId=:TeacherId order by **T.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1**";

Answer (score 0):

Since tagged hql you can try something like below. Updating only the latest one based on pk.

```
UPDATE Studenttable T set T.timestamp=:time,T.Action=:action where T.StudentId=:studentId and T.teacherId=:TeacherId
and T.pk = (select max(tb.pk) from Studenttable tb where tb.StudentId=:studentId and tb.teacherId=:TeacherId )
```

Comment: This will return "You can't return target table for update in from clause" ... Thanks though. I will keep trying.